# Way to get information on whether or not a property is set readonly in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, properties, readonly, objective-c-runtime

I have got some properties in objective-c that are declared readonly such as:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString* aProperty;
```

And I want to get information on the properties readability to treat them differently (e.g. change the way how information about them is displayed in the GUI). Thats why I need a way to ask if the property is readonly (I have got a list of property names and their objects in which they are contained). Is there a way to achieve this? - for example using the objective-c runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    objc_property_t prop = class_getProperty([object class], [aProperty UTF8String]);
    if (!prop) {
       // doesn't exist for object
       return nil;
    }
    const char * propAttr = property_getAttributes(prop);
    NSString *propString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:propAttr];
    NSArray *attrArray = [propString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

attrArray will contain all the properties refer to this [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html)

Comment: Note that properties are frequently declared readonly publicly and readwrite privately.   Not sure how that might impact this code.

Answer (score 1):

To make it easy & fast:

```
objc_property_t prop = class_getProperty([object class], "aProperty");
const char * roAttr *property_copyAttributeValue(property, "R");
```

1. I do not believe, that properties are encoded using UTF8. ;-) But it should not make any difference.
2. This way, you do not have to construct many instances of NSString.
3. You do not have to pick-up the desired attribute.
4. Always have a look to the headers. It is a part of the documentation. (property_copyAttribteValue() is only documentated at runtime.h.)
5. Consider using object_getClass() instead of [object class]. This depends on the task, you have to solve.

Comment: Well, it's either UTF-8 or ASCII and anything encoded correctly in ASCII is also encoded correctly in UTF-8, so there's no problem there.